# Present new alert immediately after previous one is dismissed Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to test an alert generator I made by generating one alert after another, but the second alert I realized can never be presented because the previous one isn't dismissed.  How would I make it so that the second alert is called immediately after the first is dismissed.  Here is what I have for the alert definitions:

```
let test1: UIAlertController = alertGenerator(title: "test1", message: "test1", actions: settings)
let test2: UIAlertController = alertGenerator(title: "Test2", message: "test2", actions: cancel)
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied {
    print("Authorization Denied")
    self.present(test1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
self.present(test2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if you had access to each `UIAlertAction`. The you could present the next alert in the handler for the alert action that closes the previous alert.

Comment: What are `actions`?  You will need to set up some sort of closure or delegate method that can be called from each action so you know when each alert has been dismissed

Comment: Are you constrained to use `alertGenerator` ?

Comment: I'm not constrained to use alertGenerator, since I'm starting off swift, I thought I'd challenge myself and make a function to do this.  Actions is a variadic parameter of alertGenerator so that when it is called, all those actions are implemented.  I'll remove alertGenerator though and see if that helps.